# Retrive data from chatbot to our application

Tags: java, spring

How can I add a chatbot into my web application and how can I process the user input message to our code?

Comment: If you're asking how to implement a chatbot, that question is too broad. If you're asking for a chatbot library you can include, library recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: could  I use any API's to implement chatbot

Answer (score 0):

It is a vast question to ask about how to implement and add a chatbot in a web application. For example, to implement a chatbot if you use DialogFlow then you have to make its WebHook fulfillment also where you will get the data from user and you can process and produce output on the basis of that.